# Transfer files from Unix to Winxp server using Jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I'm writing a Java program, to transfer files from Unix server to Windows using the JSch library :) 
Maybe someone could help me find some example code on how to download a file? I am looking for functions something like these:

```
Jsch new= Jsch(); 
new.downloadFilesFromServer(String filename);

new.saveFileLocation(String location)    //   i mean the right function names
```

I tried the simple JSch example and I can connect to server, complete one operation, and disconnect. So far the only functions I've found in documentation were more-or-less connecting to the server or disconnecting, but not the file download functions, or a JSch full tutorial (if one exists :D ).

Comment: Did you think about vfs (apache.commons)? There's jsch somwhere inside, I think, but they provide a clear, easy to use api.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ScpFrom](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java) jsch example which shows you how to copy a remote file to somewhere local.

Comment: Hi @dogbane maybe you know if I should get this error comopiling  with netbeans(its probably because i havent entered command line parameters username,address and file names?!):                                 usage: java ScpFrom user@remotehost:file1 file2
Java Result: -1
      System.exit(-1);
    }

Comment: Furthermore you can't enter a password here lol , so how can you connect to a server?! :D

Comment: @user615927 according to the code, it will pop up a gui to enter the username and password.